# using bean in normal class in spring mvc 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring and hibernate to create a website.
I'm using custom Tag to load a specific html (on string format) using template. The problem is that I can't use the bean that I defined in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. I did it normally when using controller. 
In more specifically: 
I have a template (html file), and a class (GenTemplate.java) to generate the template into string (using Jtpl) then I use custom tag to print that string into jsp file. I also get data from database when generating the template. However, when getting data from DAO class, I get null pointer exception (I get the result correctly when using controller). So I think I should get the bean that was defined in dispatcher file for accessing into the database 
I have implemented `ApplicationContextAware` and `ServletContextAware` but I were all get the `null pointer exception`. 
So how can I get the bean that is defined in dispatcher file?

Comment: you have to specify your question..

Comment: you want to use beans in a jsp tag impliementation?

Comment: No, let say I have a template, and a class (GenTemplate.java) to generate the template into string (JTPL) then I use custom tag to print that string into jsp file. 
I also get data from database when generating the template. However, when I get data from DAO class, I get null pointer exception (I get the result correctly when using controller). So I think I should get the bean that was defined in dispatcher file for accessing into the database

Comment: How do you get your DAO bean? And what is `null`, the bean? You should post some code.